# How to edit a textview where the value is assigned using a baseadapter from a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a class that extends baseadapter to assign values to two textviews, I then call this class in the main activity and initialise it with the values for the two textviews. I then set the adapter class to a listview. 
What I want to do when the user clicks on the list a AlertDialog with a edittext pops up and the user can enter a new value and append that back to the listview. I'm having trouble implementing this, please help.

EDIT

This method shows the alertdialog

```
public void editInfo(final String item, final List<Info> list, final int position, final String    itemTitle, final InfoAdapter adapter)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Edit "+item+"?");
    //Create a Layout where all the views will be appened
    LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText inputEdit = new EditText(this);
    //Declare all the properties for the email inputBox
    inputEdit.setHint(item);
    inputEdit.setSingleLine(true);
    myLayout.addView(inputEdit);
    // add all the EditTexts into the alertdialog view
    alert.setView(myLayout);
    //Declare the variable that will be returned
    alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
            //Get all the values from the input boxes
            editItem = inputEdit.getText().toString();
            //Validate all the data before doing anything with it
            if(editItem.equals(""))
            {
                showEnterValuesToast();
                editInfo(item,list,position,itemTitle,adapter);
            }else
            {        
                list.set(position, new Info(itemTitle, item));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
    }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

This is the listView's setOnItemClickListener

```
final InfoAdapter adapter = new InfoAdapter(this, listOfInfo);

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long index)
     {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                    String itemToEditName = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditName,listOfInfo,position,"Name",adapter);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    String itemToEditSurname = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditSurname,listOfInfo,position,"Surname",adapter);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    String itemToEditEmail = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditEmail, listOfInfo, position,"Email",adapter);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    String itemToEditDate = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditDate,listOfInfo,position,"Date Of Birth",adapter);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    String itemToEditAddress = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditAddress,listOfInfo,position,"Physical Address",adapter);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    String itemToEditPostal = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditPostal,listOfInfo,position,"Postal Code",adapter);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    String itemToEditNumber = listOfInfo.get(position).getItem();
                    editInfo(itemToEditNumber,listOfInfo,position,"Phone Number",adapter);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have added some code, @AntonSavin.

Comment: So what doesn't work?